# How can I sort data for a variable with repeating values in cycles using Stata?

Tags: sorting, stata

I am conducting a study on consumer preference. Respondents were asked to choose 1 of the 3 products `pid` based on a set of attributes `colour texture price`.

Please help with Stata commands to sort the following data by `pid`. The sorted data should have values of "pid" sorted in cycles of 1-3.

Here is part of the data:

```
clear
input colour texture price pid
1 2 1900 1
2 1 1300 2
0 0 0 3
1 1 1700 1
2 2 1900 2
0 0 0 3
1 1 1500 1
2 2 1700 1
0 0 0 1
2 2 1300 1
1 1 1900 1
0 0 0 1
1 2 1900 1
2 1 1500 2
0 0 0 2
1 1 1300 2
2 2 1700 2
0 0 0 2
2 1 1700 2
1 2 1300 2
0 0 0 3
2 1 1500 3
1 2 1700 3
0 0 0 3
2 2 1500 3
1 1 1700 3
0 0 0 3
end
```

I tried ChatGPT and Sonic AI. Both AI programs recommended the commands below which did not work.

```
gen cycle = mod(pid-1,3)+1
egen group_var = seq(), block(3)
gen cycle = _n % 3
```

Comment: `_n % 3` is not legal Stata code as `%` is not an operator in Stata. Otherwise unless you have an identifier for each person the data look hopelessly jumbled to me. Who knows which triple belongs together?

Answer (score 0):

With this solution the order of `colour`, `texture` and `price` is not fixed.

```
bysort pid: gen temp = _n
sort temp pid
drop temp
```

It would probably be better to sort like (if every combination of (`colour`, `texture`, `price`) exists and is unique)

```
sort colour texture price pid
```

Comment: This is not what was asked. The OP wants cycles over 1 2 3, presumably for different customers, but after observation 6 in the data ezample I see no discernible order. ,